# Heisenbug with Julia's parse?

Tags: parsing, debugging, casting, type-conversion, julia

On [today's Advent of Code](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/4) I needed to parse strings into integers. The function I wrote for that was

```
function fd(s::String, fromto::UnitRange)::Bool
    try
        parse(UInt, s) in fromto
    catch ArgumentError
        false
    end    
end
```

That function was called several times within an `isvalid` which was called for all inputs to count the number of valid things.

The result was always 0 and the respective tests kept failing. Then I extracted one of the failing test things and debugged into `isvalid`, **it passed!**

I rearraged a few things and tested more, the same thing kept happening:

1. Running the code regularly, `fd` never returned `true`.
2. When stepping through, I got `true` where expected.

After replacing the `parse` to

```
function fd(s::String, fromto::UnitRange)::Bool
    parsed = tryparse(UInt, s)
    if isnothing(parsed)
        false
    else
        parsed in fromto
    end
end
```

it immediately worked always and the exercise was solved.

Shouldn't these two versions of the function always return the same result? What happened here?

#### Update1

This was the example that I used:

```
println("Sample is ", isvalid(Dict(
    "hcl" => "#623a2f",   # check with regex
    "ecl" => "grn",       # checked with set
    "pid" => "087499704", # check with regex
    "hgt" => "74in",      # check with regex
    "iyr" => "2012",      # this was parsed
    "eyr" => "2030",      # this was parsed
    "byr" => "1980",      # this was parsed
)))
```

#### Update 2

This post only has a subset of the code. If you want to try yourself, you can get the full file at [GitHub](https://github.com/CmdQ/AoC2020/blob/heisenbug/AoC2020/src/04.jl). I also recorded a [video](https://youtu.be/9fPzdRzNSdI) showing the differing behavior with and without debugging.

The thing is demonstrated quite clearly with `@assert fd("2010", 2000:2020) == fdt("2010", 2000:2020)` failing in one scenario and not in the other.

Comment: Can you provide example input where the result differs?

Comment: Of course, sorry.

Comment: This gives (not surprisingly): `ERROR: MethodError: no method matching isvalid(::Dict{String, String})`

Comment: @StefanKarpinski, you'll now find the full code and a video linked. Sorry it took a while.